# Can I use 53-39T chain rings with compact cranks?

Tags: maintenance

I have shimano 105 5700 compact  crank(50-34T).
Can I use 53-39T chain rings with compact right arm.

Comment: As stated in the answer below, what you need to look for is the bolt circle diameter (BCD) of your crank. The crank **arm** has no impact on compact or standard chainrings.

Answer (score 6):

When you're matching chainrings to a crank, you need to match the bolt pattern (i.e. are there 4 bolts, 5 bolts) and the bolt circle diameter (BCD) measured in mm -- the diameter of the circle which all the bolts lie on [or equivalently, the center-to-center distance (C-C) of adjacent bolts. Multiply this (in mm) by 1.701 to get the BCD for 5 bolt patterns, 1.414 for 4 bolt, etc. -- its just a simple exercise in trigonometry to figure this out].

Compact cranks have a 110 BCD with a 5 bolt pattern while a regular road double has 130 BCD 5 bolt pattern.

There are some 53t and 39t 110 BCD chainrings, but they are less common than those sold in 130 BCD. As pointed out by ojs in the comments, Stronglight and TA (among other manufacturers) do make them.

Note that you will also have to adjust the front derailleur (and check everything is within spec for the front derailleur) if you do this swap. And you defeat the point of buying a compact double in the first place.

Comment: These sizes are easily available from third party manufacturers like Stronglight and TA. I'm not naming any names, but many European mail order shops have these and will ship everywhere in the world.

Comment: @ojs - Thanks. I'd seen a 53t 110 bcd ring but not a 39t 110 bcd before. I think with Euro-US shipping and the prices i found for the 110 bcd rings, I'd probably opt for just buying the regular 105 double crank (which is about 110 dollars), and maybe selling the 105 compact crank.